# MakeAppx for ARM?

Tags: msbuild, windows-runtime, windows-store, appx

I want to create WindowsStore appx packages from the commandline. We have an X86 and ARM version of our app (.NET). As it's referencing sqlite, Any CPU is not possible.

There is the MakeAppx tool, but it's only available for x86/x64.
How do I create an ARM package?

Basically I would like to automate what "rightclick winstore project -> store -> create app packages" does.
I heard calling msbuild with publish should create an appx, but the only thing it creates for me is an .appxrecipe.

Any one done this build automation properly yet?

edit:so the solution was to simply call the x86 makeappx on the ARM bin folder...

Comment: Although MakeAppx utility runs only on x86/x64, it should be able to produce packages targeting any architecture.  The architecture is specified in the AppxManifest.xml file.  For an example, you can actually create a package using VS, rename the .appx file to .zip file and look at the file called AppXManifest.xml inside it

Comment: MSBuild with Publish should create an appx, just as you said. Are you checking the right folder? There should be one with your project's name that has an appx, a .psd1, a .cer, and a folder of resources.

Comment: Oh man... how could I not see it the whole time??? thanks :D